# How to print a string representation of linked list class

Tags: python, linked-list

I am implementing a linked list in Python 3. I am trying to get output such as `"1  2  3"` with two spaces in between. My current code prints out `"1  2  3  "` instead:

```
  def __str__ (self):
    current = self.first
    if (current == None):
      return None
    while (current.next != None):
      for i in range(1,10):
        if current != None or current != '':
          print(current.data,'  ',end='')
          current = current.next
```

How do I get rid of the last two spaces?

Comment: `current.rstrip(' ')` should remove trailing spaces.

Comment: What's `for i in range(1,10):` doing here?

Comment: Note that `print()` inserts a single space. between the things it prints, by default. In this case, you're printing two things, `current.data`, and `'  '`. Not only will `rstrip()` not help here, as the extra spaces have already been printed, there will be THREE spaces after each item.

Answer (score 2):

In Python you would typically use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to build a string from a collection of items with some constant separator. This takes care of the problem of having an extra separator at one or the other end of your string.

But you need to give `str.join()` an iterable. Judging by what you've shown of your code, you should be able to make this class iterable by defining the `__iter__` method as something like:

```
def __iter__(self):
    current = self.first
    while current is not None:
        yield current
        current = current.next
```

For more details about the `yield` keyword and iterables, I recommend reading [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/2359271).

Note also that [PEP 8 recommends using `is not None` rather than `!= None`:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or
>   `is not`, never the equality operators

Once the linked list is iterable, your string representation is as easy as:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '  '.join(str(o) for o in self)  # two spaces between each item
```

Keep in mind when writing `__str__` methods that [you should *return* a string object, not print one in the body of the method.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13394046/2359271)

Comment: The iterable passed to `str.join()` must yield strings, too: `return '  '.join(str(item) for item in self)`

Comment: @BlacklightShining Good catch. I neglected to test whether `join` would implicitly use the `__str__` of the iterable's elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just a blind guess:

```
def __str__ (self):
    current = self.first
    def get_data():
        current = current.next
        return current.data
    return " ".join([self.first.data] + list(iter(get_data,None)))
```

Would you mind sharing your linked list implementation?